# SQL Query to insert values from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a 2 table structure:

### Table A:

```
RID; Name; LP
E    F     1
E    F     2
E    F     3
E    F     12
E    F     152
```

### Table B:

```
LP
1
2
3
12
152
...
156
157
180
itd.
```

Query something like:

```
Insert into TableA(RID, Name, LP) Values ('E', 'F', Select LP from TableB)
```

I want to achive:

```
RID; Name; LP
E    F     1
E    F     2
E    F     3
E    F     12
E    F     152
E    F     156
E    F     157
E    F     180
etc.
```

Comment: Which database - sql-server or postgresql?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close. Try

```
INSERT INTO TableA(RID, Name, LP)
SELECT 'E', 'F', LP FROM TableB
-- Omit this where clause, if duplicate LP's are OK
WHERE TableB.LP NOT IN (SELECT LP FROM TableA)
```

Comment: Can you do this in JOOQ?

Comment: @Friso: Of course! Feel free to ask a new question about it and I'll answer

Comment: @Lucas Eder, after a lot of puzzling I figured it out. Might post something anyway if I find the time as it maybe helpful to others. Thank for the reply (and your great work!)

Comment: @Friso: Sure! It's common practice here on Stack Overflow to answer your own questions to help future visitors. Looking forward!

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into TableA(RID, Name, LP) 
Select 
   'E', 'F', LP 
 from 
   TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

The "quick and dirty" solution i came up with is :

`Insert into TableA(RID, Name, LP) Values ('E', 'F', Select LP from TableB where rowid = 1)`

`Insert into TableA(RID, Name, LP) Values ('E', 'F', Select LP from TableB where rowid = 2)`

...

and so on...

Comment: That is really "quick and dirty" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

select * into [NEW_TABLE] from  [OLD_TABLE]

### No need to create new table. It'll be created automatically.

Enjoy.